# javascript create dynamic class by object

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, es6-class, es6-proxy

**Task: I want to create a dynamic class by a given JSON Object in ES6.**

After a lot of reading in the MDN web docs and much stackoverflow questions i'm totally confused how to get this work.

**JSON Object**

```
{
    constructor: {
        name: "someName",
    },
    getter: {
        function1: () => "someOutput",
        function2: () => false,
    }
}
```

While I tried to solve the problem I figured out how to create dynamic getter methods by using "**Proxy**" or "**defineProperty**" but how i should handle the constructor?? :(

I hope someone can help me with a hint or an example.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not change your backend to return actual JavaScript rather than JSON?

Comment: I cant change my Backend :( i get this object from a api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add constructor to your class created by Proxy using Proxy's "construct" handler method:

```
const jsonObj = {
    constructor: {
        name: "someName",
    },
    getter: {
        function1: () => "someOutput",
        function2: () => false,
    }
}


function baseClass(obj) {
  for(i in obj){
    this[i] = obj[i]

  }
}

const handler = {
  construct(target, args) {
    return new target(jsonObj.constructor);
  }
};

const NewClass = new Proxy(baseClass, handler);
```